# Geofence - satellite contact time

Tags: spacecraft, communication-satellite, astrodynamics, ground-station, ground-track

I need to find the access/contact times for a satellite passing through a random geofence (polygon). Is there a python library or any code to integrate the geofence to the orbit of the satellite to know: time, lat, long, duration of contact?

Answer (score 3):

To directly integrate a Geofence polygon I'm not sure, but MAYBE [Skifield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) could work?? Depending on how detailed you need it to be.

It has a EarthSatellite object that is initialized using TLEs and a find_event method that returns all the instants a satellite starts or ends passes over a given point during a specified time range. You just need to specify a point on the ground using latitude and longitude, minimum inclination, and the initial and final time of the time range. [EarthSatellite](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-satellites.html)

You could use this for all the vertices of the polygon and even intermediate points based on the resolution you need, and create a couple of functions that use the passes information to obtain all the data you need.